# Get a error list after validate xml against a schema file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xsd

I´m validating a XML file against a schema xsd. So far so good, the code generates a exception in case of failure.

```
        bool isValid = true;
        List<string> errorList = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Schemas.Add(null, schemaFilePath);
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.LoadXml(xml);
            XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(document.InnerXml), settings);
            while (rdr.Read()) { }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorList.Add(ex.Message);
            isValid = false;
        }

        LogErrors(errorList);
        return isValid;
```

But I need that the code build a list of all errors found in the validate before send it to my log, instead of always show only the first one found.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your catch does nothing with the error. What is the error you are getting, and why are you not doing anything with it?

Comment: Why don't you return an Exception instead? And then simply log it, or put is on an array or a list.

Comment: The exception holds only one error at the time an then exits the verification. I want to store all errors in a list and then return it to be handled.

The code above is just an example that I found.

Comment: _"the exception holds..."_ Where is this exception you speak of? Your catch squashes any exception. Yes it is true that the function will return `false` when it encounters the first error, but you don't even know what the error is!

Comment: It's not that hard to understand what I want to do, but I changed the code. I hope is more understandable now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `Validate` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162371.aspx) with a  `ValidationEventHandler`. you can follow MSDN's way of creating the `ValidationEventHandler` separately or do it inline if you want.

e.g

```
    //...Other code above
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(pathXMLCons);
    document.Validate((o, e) => 
                      { 
                          //Do your error logging through e.message 
                      });
```

If you don't do this, a `XmlSchemaValidationException` will be thrown and only that one can be caught.

Comment: Glad the answer helped :)

Answer (score 3):

I tried XmlDocument which failed in my case.
The below code should work
Courtesy: C#5.0 in a nutshell

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("contosoBooks.xml");
XmlSchemaSet set = new XmlSchemaSet();
set.Add(null, "contosoBooks.xsd");
StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();
doc.Validate(set, (sender,args) => { errors.AppendLine(args.Exception.Message); });
Console.WriteLine(errors);
```